# Bison: is it possible to manipulate the parser stacks during reduction?

Tags: bison

In scanner, there is a function called `unput()`. In parser, I am wondering is there a similar utilities to manipulate the stacks?

My scenario:

In scanner, by checking the input string, I can determine the corresponding character to be used in `unput()`. e.g., I `unput()` `'2'` for an identifier starts with `d`, `'4'` for `q`, `'8'` for `o`, etc.

I also have a simple identifier alias feature, which allows to define identifiers with friendly names (e.g., `#define NAME   d0`), all are placed at the beginning of the input file. This feature is implemented by just a hash table in `.y`, the hash table can keep all info about `NAME`, `d0`, and `2`.

Now in the production rule, when I encounter a use of `NAME` identifier, by looking up the hash table, I can reduce it to symbol corresponding to `d0`, but the information about `2` is lost... Since in scanner, non-aliased string `d0` maps to two symbols, but `NAME` only maps to a single symbol. That's why I want to push an extra symbol corresponding to `2` into the stacks *somehow*, hoping that it behaviors the same as if the scanner was reading `d0`.

Comment: If you want to do something like macro replacement, it probably makes more sense to do it in the scanner rather than the parser (or as a separate layer between the scanner and parser).  Trying to modify the parser state stack makes little sense and is likely to be impossible to get right.

Answer (score -1):

There's only one way to play with the stack: using $0, $-1, etc. to change the values (and @0... for locations), but you cannot change the type of the symbol.